# Magento dropshipper e-mails

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, email

I am making an extension that filters each order and send out an e-mail to each drop shipper in order.

**Example**

Order with 3 products. 2 products from drop shippers A and 1 product from drop shipper B.

Dropshipper A with should receive email containing only their 2 products and drop shipper B should receive email containing just their 1 product.

I want to maintain default Magento e-mail template functionality, so email is easy to update.

This is what i have so far.

Observer model that listen for `<sales_order_place_after>`

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <sales_order_place_after_handler>
                <type>model</type>
                <class>dropshipperemail/observer</class>
                <method>sendEmail</method>
            </sales_order_place_after_handler>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

A method in observer that filter products and build array containing correct data.

```
public function sendEmail(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getOrder();     
    $orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems(); 

    foreach($orderItems as $item):          
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($item->getProductId());
        if($dropshipper = $product->getAttributeText('dropshipper')):
            $list[$dropshipper][$product->getSku()] = array(
                'name' => $product->getName(),
                'sku' => $product->getSku(),
                'qty' => $item->getData('qty_ordered'),
                'price' => $item->getPrice()
            );
        endif;
    endforeach;
}
```

I can pass variables to transactional email and send fine.

But what i would like to do and i think is more elegant solution is to somehow rewrite queueNewOrderEmail and pass params with it (recipient email and product attribute to filter) like `queueNewOrderEmail(false, $dropshipper, $recipient)`. Then i can do the actual filtering in render file

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

Will this be working solution or am i missing something important?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, if other need similar solution. The suggested approach is working.

> /app/code/local/DM/DropshipperEmail/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
        <DM_DropshipperEmail>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </DM_DropshipperEmail>
    </modules>
  <global>
        <helpers>
            <dropshipperemail>
                <class>DM_DropshipperEmail_Helper</class>
            </dropshipperemail>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <dropshipperemail>
                <class>DM_DropshipperEmail_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>dropshipperemail_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </dropshipperemail>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <sales_order_place_after_handler>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>dropshipperemail/observer</class>
                        <method>sendEmail</method>
                    </sales_order_place_after_handler>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

> /app/code/local/DM/DropshipperEmail/Model/Observer.php

```
class DM_DropshipperEmail_Model_Observer
{

    public function sendEmail(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
            $order = $observer->getOrder();     
            $orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
            $storeId = 6;   // lagersalg

            $recipients = array(
                'dropshipperA'      =>  'a@dropshipper.com',
                'dropshipperB'      =>  'b@dropshipper.com',
                'dropshipperC'      =>  'c@dropshipper.com',
            );

            foreach($orderItems as $item)
            {       
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($item->getProductId());
                if($_dropshipper = $product->getAttributeText('dropshipper'))
                {
                    $list[$_dropshipper][$product->getSku()] = array(
                            'name' => $product->getName(),
                            'sku' => $product->getSku(),
                            'qty' => $item->getData('qty_ordered'),
                            'price' => $item->getPrice()
                    );
                }
            }

            if(count($list))
            {
                foreach($list as $dropshipper => $data)
                {
                    $order->queueNewOrderEmail(false, $dropshipper, $recipients[$dropshipper]);
                    Mage::log('Email sent to dropshipper ' . $dropshipper . ' [' . $recipients[$dropshipper] . '] for order #' . $order->getIncrementId(), null, 'dropshipper.log');
                }
            }

            return $this;

        }

}
```

I then modified `queueNewOrderEmail` in `/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` to get variable `$dropshipper` and `$recipient`.

I updated dropshipper e-mail with:

```
    if($recipient != ''):
        $emailInfo->addTo($recipient, $customerName);
    else:
        $emailInfo->addTo($this->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
    endif;
```

and changed e-mail template with:

```
    if($dropshipper != ''){
        $templateId = 30;
        $customerName = $dropshipper;   
    } elseif ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
    } else {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
    }
```

In email template i added the dropshipper variables with

`{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order dropshipper=$dropshipper}}`

Then in `/app/design/frontend/hvidtogfrit/lagersalg/template/email/order/items.phtml` i am now able to filter products with `$dropshipper = $this->getDropshipper()` and compare this to product attribute.

Please note you also need to modify `$this->getChildHtml('order_totals')` to get the numbers to match the products, as you are now removing products from the order e-mail.